# Why brower is not loading static files?

Tags: django, django-2.2

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

django.contrib.staticfiles' included in installed_apps. {% load static from staticfiles %} used in base.html.
still getting these errors:

```
[22/Dec/2019 13:45:31] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10735
[22/Dec/2019 13:45:32] "GET /static/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 
1791
[22/Dec/2019 13:45:43] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 
1788
[22/Dec/2019 13:45:43] "GET /static/css/mdb.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1770
......
```

script.html

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js' 
%}"> 
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"> 
</script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"> 
</script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mdb.min.js' %}"> 
</script>
<!-- Initializations -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Animations initialization
new WOW().init();

</script>
```

staticfiles dir includes following files and folders

static_in_env

```
 - css
   -bootstrap.css
   -bootstrap.min.css
   -mdb.css
   -mdb.min.css
   -mdb.lite.css
   -mdb.lite.min.css
   -style.css
   -style.min.css
 - font
 - img
 - js
    -bootstrap.js
    -bootstrap.min.js
    -mdb.js
    -mdb.min.js
    -popper.min.js
 - scss
```

Comment: post your base.html file also to see the static links

Comment: Are you talking about `dev` or `prod`? Running locally or deployed on a server?

Comment: @KrazyMax dev. running locally

Comment: @bmons {% include 'script.html' %} used on base.html

Comment: I guess you have a `js` directory in your `static_in_env` directory? Do not hesitate to add as much details as possible, such as the tree of your repo.

Comment: where are your css file links?

Comment: @KrazyMax I dont know how to add folder structure here. I tried to do my best. I hope it is understandable

Answer (score 1):

In your `project_name/urls.py`, try to add the following at the end:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # your urls...
]

# ↓ add this ↓
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also, just put `{% load static %}` in your `script.html`, not `{% load static from staticfiles %}`

Comment: I was using `{% load static %}` before `{% load static from staticfiles }` somebody suggested that might work.

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py add

```
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In base.html

```
{% load static %}
```

Hopefully it will work if it doesn't run this command

```
Python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: did that already. still not working. Putting forward slash also didn't make difference

Comment: If running locally with `python manage.py runserver`, `collectstatic` will be of no help unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstap, either you download it or use cdn

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or you can use the starter template provided by bootstrap, which will have all the basic html,css and js files. Link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/
custom css links can be linked to the file as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}"/>
```

Comment: yeah it worked but not the way it was supposed to. Still a good alternative.Thanks

Comment: It works for external resources, but the problem will remain if OP wants to use custom static files. It does not solve OP issue!